# trignometry -heights and distances

Tags: geometry

A man standing x metres north of a tower finds angle of elevation of it's top to be 30 degree.He then starts walking a distance of x/2 metres ,he turns east and walks another x/2 metres.Then he turns south and walks another x/2 metres.The angle of elevation of the top of the tower from his new position is ?

Comment: did you even try anything lol

Comment: and which way does he begin walking initially

Comment: he walked towards the tower initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He begins $x$ meters north of the tower, where it is at a $30º$ elevation.

After walking $\displaystyle \frac x2$ meters towards the tower(south), $\displaystyle \frac x2$ meters east, then $\displaystyle \frac x2$ meters south, he is now $\displaystyle \frac{x}{2}$ meters east of the tower.

We know that, by SOH-CAH-TOA, that if the tower forms $30º$ with the ground, that the tower is $\displaystyle \tan(30)*x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$ meters tall.

Therefore, if he is $\displaystyle \frac{x}{2}$ meters away from the tower, and the tower is $\displaystyle \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$  meters tall, he forms a $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ angle.

Notice this is because the slope is $\displaystyle \frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}}{\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: options include: A)15º  B)60º C)tan-1(sqrt(2/3))  D)tan-1(2/√3)

Comment: can you please help on this

Comment: i'm sorry i made a mistake. :) it's answer choice D.